# Prevent line break before inline-block element

Tags: html, css, line-breaks

I would like to show a quotes. Both at the start and the end of the quote, there is a quotation mark, shown as a background image. There should never be a line break between the starting quotation mark and the first word of the quote, or between the last word in the quote and the ending quotation mark. To achieve this I have tried using `white-space: nowrap;`. The following snippet does what I'm after:

```css
.quote {
  width: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;
}
.quote-text {
  white-space: normal;
}
.quote-start,
.quote-end {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="quote">
   <span class="quote-start"></span>
   <span class="quote-text">text that is wrapped over several lines</span>
   <span>&#xfeff;</span>
   <span class="quote-end"></span>
</div>
```

You can test it in this [CodePen](http://codepen.io/Stadly/pen/dXXYOe).

But is there any way to do this without the ugly `<span>&#xfeff;</span>`?

Comment: How is an element that has a width of 20px supposed to fit in a line that has a width of 10px?

Comment: You wouldnt need white-space: nowrap for the entire quote. That would make your whole quote non breakable.

Comment: @connexo: The with is narrow to force breaking of words. Then it's easy to check that the quoatation marks are on the same line as the first and last word.

Comment: @ArathiSreekumar: I set white-space: normal; for the quote-text.

Comment: Ah, ok. Missed that one, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can before and after pseudo elements. Do u want this? Check the codepen and reply.
http://codepen.io/SESN/pen/MeeaGp

```
 .quote {
  width: 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background: red;

}
.quote:before, .quote:after { content: ""; position: relative; background: url(http://1axcbc2mo5e72fuf7p2ouonc.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/left-quotation-marks.png) no-repeat; background-size: contain; padding: 0px 5px 0px 10px;
} 

.quote:after { }
.quote-text {
  white-space: normal;
}
.quote-start,
.quote-end {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
}
```

Comment: Nice idea. In your Pen, you don't have display: block on the quotation marks. Therefore the width and height cannot be specified. If display: block is added, the quotation marks are not positioned on the same line as the first and last word.

Comment: Yes, i removed it from Pen. What is ur actual reuqirement for you

Comment: I would like to use a background image to show the quotation marks, so it must be possible to set the width and height of the quotation mark containers.

Comment: Check out the codepen i have updated for the image thing

Comment: Adjust padding and change the image for quote close mark.